# Is there a way to detect u8"" literals at preprocessor or compile time in C?

Tags: c, string-literals, c11

C11 now provides several kinds of string literal:

- `"old school literals"`
- `u8"UTF-8 encoded literals"`
- `u"char16_t encoded literals"`
- `U"char32_t encoded literals"`
- `L"wchar_t literals, whatever size it may be"`

Because of the different types involved, one could discriminate the differently-sized literals using a `_Generic()` expression. Sadly, there is no size nor type difference between native `"quoted literals"` and `u8"quoted literals."`

I wondered if preprocessor magic could be used, but it appears that GCC either treats the `u8"text"` as an indivisible token, or it eats the `u8` during an early stage. Regardless, I wasn't able to grab the "u8" prefix with a macro. :-(

So, I am left to wonder: is there any way to differentiate between native-encoded literals and UTF-8 encoded literals without "just knowing"?

The context is my library code wanting to intelligently convert a passed string to UTF-8. If I can wrap the calls in a macro that figures out whether I need to transcode the string, that would be great. (Otherwise, of course, I have to rely on the user. And you know what an idiot he is.)

Comment: I see one huge problem here: What if user is using old-school strings in UTF-8 encoded file, and compiler let's it through as is? Then you would convert UTF-8 string to UTF-8 string and possibly mess up contents. It's impossible to check between old school 8-bit encoding and UTF-8 without guessing, and quessing almost always wrong thing to do when it comes to encoding. I don't think attempting to automatically convert between these 2 types is right way to go.

Comment: `is my library code wanting to intelligently convert a passed string to UTF-8` As I know how hard it is to use standard C interface for string conversion, let [my code be an inspiration](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/-/blob/master/src/yio/private/yio_strlib.c#L134) for conversion functions. The other way is to use a different type for UTF-8, like `(uint8_t*)u8"stuff"`, but as noted, the user will not always follow convention.

Comment: *the user will not always follow convention* - this is true. But what I am trying to do is discover the cases where the user **provided** information, and not lose that. If the user enters `"foo"` then I simply have no data. But if the user enters `u8"foo"` I don't want to throw away the data that I did have! It's the difference between `.encoding=NULL` and `.encoding="UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_Generic` and then do some pre-processor trick to tell the difference. First the `_Generic` part, which in this case I made to return a string for printing:

```
#define LITERAL_TYPE(s)            \
  _Generic((s),                    \
           char*: U8_TYPE(s),      \
           wchar_t*: "wchar_t",    \
           char16_t*: "char16_t",  \
           char32_t*: "char32_t")
```

Then the `U8_TYPE` macro:

```
#define U8_TYPE(s) (#s[0]=='\"'? "old school":"u8")
```

This macro simply checks if the first character in the pre-processor token is a `"` or not. It can be made a bit more advanced and look for `'u'` and `'8'` as well, with some `&&` checks, though you have to check for the ending `'"'` too in that case so that you don't access out of bounds.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <uchar.h>

#define U8_TYPE(s) (#s[0]=='\"'? "old school":"u8")

#define LITERAL_TYPE(s)            \
  _Generic((s),                    \
           char*: U8_TYPE(s),      \
           wchar_t*: "wchar_t",    \
           char16_t*: "char16_t",  \
           char32_t*: "char32_t")

int main(void)
{
   puts(LITERAL_TYPE("hello"));
   puts(LITERAL_TYPE(L"hello"));
   puts(LITERAL_TYPE(u8"hello"));
   puts(LITERAL_TYPE(u"hello"));
   puts(LITERAL_TYPE(U"hello"));
}
```

Output:

```
old school
wchar_t
u8
char16_t
char32_t
```

Comment: There is one case where it will fail - `puts(LITERAL_TYPE("" u8"hello"));`, but that is a corner case.

Comment: Noice! I tried using `##` to grab the u8 as a preprocessor symbol, I didn't think about being able to stringize it. According to godbolt, this produces a comparison in the generated assembly (with no -O) for clang, gcc, and icc. (MSVC doesn't work, but that may just be down to me not knowing how to request the right standard.) In all three compilers, just a hint of -O eliminates the comparison (since it's usually something like "load 34; compare with 34; jump if n?eq"). Anyway, this defers the answer to the last possible point, but the answer *is* there. Kudos!